# Place longtblr caption below table

Tags: tables, tabularray

By default, the `longtblr` environment of the `tabularray` has a `caption` argument which places the caption above the table:

[image]

```
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{longtblr}[
        caption = {A breakable longtblr environment.}
    ]{
        colspec = {|cccc|},
        rowhead = 1,
    }
        \hline
        A & B & C & D \\
        \hline
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        \hline
        \pagebreak
        Value 5 & Value 6 & Value 7 & Value 8 \\
        \hline
    \end{longtblr}
\end{table}
```

**How would one place the repeated table caption `A breakable longtblr environment.` below each individual table?**

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Why you should do this? Table captions are normally above tables. To this is `longtblr` accommodate )with automatic generate continuous caption, generatein `continue on the next page` itc.- I would note broke this habeit (rule of good tipography))

Comment: Hi @Zarko, thanks for your comment. I agree that placing captions above tables is the standard, but the shared document I am editing uses captions below the table, and for uniformity I need to have this environment follow the same practice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead,middlehead,lasthead}{default}{
}
\DefTblrTemplate{firstfoot}{default}{
  \UseTblrTemplate{contfoot}{default}
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption}{default}
}
\DefTblrTemplate{middlefoot}{default}{
  \UseTblrTemplate{contfoot}{default}
  \UseTblrTemplate{capcont}{default}
}
\DefTblrTemplate{lastfoot}{default}{
  \UseTblrTemplate{note}{default}
  \UseTblrTemplate{remark}{default}
  \UseTblrTemplate{capcont}{default}
}


\begin{document}

    \centering
    \begin{longtblr}[
        caption = {A breakable longtblr environment.}
    ]{
        colspec = {|cccc|},
        rowhead = 1,
    }
        \hline
        A & B & C & D \\
        \hline
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 5 & Value 6 & Value 7 & Value 8 \\
        \hline
    \end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

This variation of [Pieter van Oostrum's nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/662182/47927) takes care as well of `longtblr`s that are *not* split over several pages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm, paper width=12cm, paper height=12cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead,middlehead,lasthead}{default}{
}
\DefTblrTemplate{firstfoot}{default}{
  \UseTblrTemplate{contfoot}{default}
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption}{default}
}
\DefTblrTemplate{middlefoot}{default}{
  \UseTblrTemplate{contfoot}{default}
  \UseTblrTemplate{capcont}{default}
}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DefTblrTemplate{lastfoot}{default}{
  \UseTblrTemplate{note}{default}
  \UseTblrTemplate{remark}{default}
  \int_compare:nNnTF { \l__tblr_table_page_int } = {1} {
    \UseTblrTemplate{caption}{default}
  } {
    \UseTblrTemplate{capcont}{default}
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

    \centering
    \begin{longtblr}[
        caption = {A breakable longtblr environment.}
    ]{
        colspec = {|cccc|},
        rowhead = 1,
    }
        \hline
        A & B & C & D \\
        \hline
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        \hline
    \end{longtblr}

    \bigskip

    \begin{longtblr}[
        caption = {A breakable longtblr environment.}
    ]{
        colspec = {|cccc|},
        rowhead = 1,
    }
        \hline
        A & B & C & D \\
        \hline
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 & Value 4 \\
        \hline
    \end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]