# How do I get the caption below the table with tabularray?

Tags: tables, tabularray

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}[%
caption = {A Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Table},
  entry = {Short Caption},
  label = {tblr:test},
  long
  ]{colspec={X}}
  More Text\\
  My text\\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

How can I get the caption below the table? (I know that this is bad advice but I am bound to certain guidelines.

[image]

---

**EDIT**

The solution proposed ([Place longtblr caption below table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/662168/place-longtblr-caption-below-table)) does not work since it adds `(Continued)` to the caption even if it is not split:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead,middlehead,lasthead}{default}{
}
\DefTblrTemplate{firstfoot}{default}{
  \UseTblrTemplate{contfoot}{default}
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption}{default}
}
\DefTblrTemplate{middlefoot}{default}{
  \UseTblrTemplate{contfoot}{default}
  \UseTblrTemplate{capcont}{default}
}
\DefTblrTemplate{lastfoot}{default}{
  \UseTblrTemplate{note}{default}
  \UseTblrTemplate{remark}{default}
  \UseTblrTemplate{capcont}{default}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}[%
caption = {A Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Table},
  entry = {Short Caption},
  label = {tblr:test},
  long
  ]{colspec={X}}
  More Text\\
  My text\\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I posted a solution [over at the other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/681954/47927) that solves your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove content of definitions for `{firstfoot,middlefoot}` and in the `\DefTblrTemplate{lastfoot}{default}` insert only `\UseTblrTemplate{caption}{default}`. For example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead,middlehead,lasthead}{default}{}
\DefTblrTemplate{firstfoot,middlefoot}{default}{}  % <---
\DefTblrTemplate{lastfoot}{default}%               % <--- 
{
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption}{default}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtblr}[%
caption = {A long long long long long long long table with caption below table},
  label = {tblr:test}
              ]{hlines, vlines,
                colspec={X}}
\lipsum[11] \\
\lipsum[66] \\
    \end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note:**
Be aware, with above settings you can not use this table as real long table anymore.