How to move the longtblr caption under the table?
I have the following code for a table:
\begin{longtblr}[caption={Recursos HW}, label={tblr:PliegoHW}]{
  colspec={Q[valign=t,0.45,halign=c]Q[valign=t,0.55,halign=c]},
  vlines,
  hlines
}

Elemento HW & Características \\
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
  \centering
  \adjustbox{valign=t, max width=0.6\linewidth, max height=0.6\linewidth}{\includegraphics{WorkstationHPZ8G4}}\\
  Workstation HP Z8 G4
\end{minipage}  &
\begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}
  Justificar texto
\end{varwidth}\\  
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
  \centering
  \adjustbox{valign=t, max width=0.9\linewidth, max height=0.9\linewidth}{\includegraphics{ChasisPXIe1095}}\\
  Chasis PXIe-1095
\end{minipage}  &
\begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}
  sdfsdfsfsd
\end{varwidth}\\
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
  \centering
  \adjustbox{valign=t, max width=0.7\linewidth, max height=0.7\linewidth}{\includegraphics{PuertosMXIPCIe8398}}\\
  PCIe-8398
\end{minipage}  &
\begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}
  sdfsdfsfsd
\end{varwidth}\\
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
  \centering
  \adjustbox{valign=t, max width=0.8\linewidth, max height=0.8\linewidth}{\includegraphics{PuertosMXIPXIe8398}}\\
  PXIe-8398
\end{minipage}  &
\begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}
  sdfsdfsfsd
\end{varwidth}\\
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
  \centering
  \adjustbox{valign=t, max width=0.9\linewidth, max height=0.9\linewidth}{\includegraphics{ComMXIPXIe8374}}\\
  PXIe-8374
\end{minipage}  &
\begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}
  sdfsdfsfsd
\end{varwidth}\\
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
  \centering
  \adjustbox{valign=t, max width=0.8\linewidth, max height=0.8\linewidth}{\includegraphics{RaidDiscosDurosPXIe8267}}\\
  PXIe-8267
\end{minipage}  &
\begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}
  sdfsdfsfsd
\end{varwidth}\\
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
  \centering
  \adjustbox{valign=t, max width=0.9\linewidth, max height=0.9\linewidth}{\includegraphics{FPGAPXIe7976R}}\\
  PXIe-7976R
\end{minipage}  &
\begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}
  sdfsdfsfsd
\end{varwidth}\\
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
  \centering
  \adjustbox{valign=t, max width=0.9\linewidth, max height=0.9\linewidth}{\includegraphics{TarjetaUSRPX310}}\\
  USRP X310
\end{minipage}  &
\begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}
  sdfsdfsfsd
\end{varwidth}\\
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
  \centering
  \adjustbox{valign=t, max width=0.9\linewidth, max height=0.9\linewidth}{\includegraphics{TwinRX}}\\
  TwinRX
\end{minipage}  &
\begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}
  sdfsdfsfsd
\end{varwidth}\\
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
  \centering
  \adjustbox{valign=t, max width=0.9\linewidth, max height=0.9\linewidth}{\includegraphics{PortatilDELLXPS139370}}\\
  Portatil Generico
\end{minipage}  &
\begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}
  \begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt]
      \item abc def abc def abc def abc def
            abc def abc def abc def abc def
            abc def abc def abc def abc def
      \item abc def abc def abc def abc def
            abc def abc def abc def abc def
            abc def abc def abc def abc def
      \item abc def abc def abc def abc def
            abc def abc def abc def abc def
            abc def abc def abc def abc def
      \item abc def abc def abc def abc def
            abc def abc def abc def abc def
            abc def abc def abc def abc def\strut
  \end{itemize}
\end{varwidth}\\
\end{longtblr}

What I want is to have the table caption under the table and just at the bottom of the last table.
I know there is another question similar to mine called "Place longtblr caption below table.", but in addition i dont want to have the "(continued)" and "Continued on next page" texts.
May someone give me a clue of how can i do that?
Thank you.

Welcome to TeX.SE! Why you should move caption to below (the end) of table. By this you will lost information about table and its continuation on next pages. Default positioning of caption in long table is deliberately done ...  If you persist to move caption, than see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/681927/ or try to use  tblr-extras package.
